# direct password setting for hdiutil not working

Tags: python-3.x, bash, printf, echo, dmg

I have been trying to execute an `os.popen` command  that creates an encrypted disk image. I am using the `hdiutil` command. When the disk image is created, the given password does not work. What am I doing wrong?

FYI: I am using MacOS Mojave.

An example would be:

```py
import os

os.popen('echo -n "password" | hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -srcfolder "some_folder" "some_folder.dmg"')
```

I have also tried using `os.system()` and `subprocess.run()`

Also, there are no error messages. The bash script works in the terminal app, but not via the python script.

Comment: @Cyrus as shown in the example, the password is password.

Comment: Try to replace `echo -n` with `printf`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you! the program works now.

Comment: `os.popen` uses a different shell than you. See: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/74329)

Comment: I suggest that you delete your first three comments because they are no longer needed.